# Vue JS : Dispatching action in Vuex doesn't return the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify for my project and I have a expandable Datatable row that when it clicks, gonna retrieve the data from server side base on ID of the row. However, can't find a right way to implement in the framework so trying to do it itself.

So here I have my datatable and notice that I have a function called getTransactionDetails(), what I did is when user click the row gonna fire this function and pass the transaction_id to work in my server-side.

```
<v-data-table
    v-bind:headers="cashierheaders"
    v-bind:items="cashierItems"
    v-bind:search="search"
    v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
    :total-items="totalItems"
    :loading="loadDatatable"
    class="cashierDatatable"
    item-key="transaction_id"
    expand
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded"  style="cursor:pointer;">
            <td> 
                <v-flex>
          <v-chip label small color="green lighten-4" class="ml-0">
            {{ props.item.transaction_id}}
          </v-chip>
        </v-flex>
       </td>
            <td>
                {{props.item.pos_transaction_id}}
            </td>
            <td>{{props.item.transaction_status}}</td>
            <td>{{props.item.business_date}}</td>
            <td>{{props.item.sale}}</td>
            <td>{{props.item.coupon}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>         
    <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">                                 
        <v-card flat dark>
            <v-layout>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 sm6>

                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 sm6>
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title>
                            <v-chip label small color="red lighten-4">Giveaways</v-chip>
                            <v-chip label small color="red lighten-4">Modifed</v-chip>
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
                        <v-card-title>
                            <!-- start of transaction -->
                                <v-list two-lines subheader dark>
                                    <v-subheader style="">

                                    </v-subheader>

                                    <template v-for="(item,index) in getTransactionDetails(props.item.transaction_id)">
                                        {{ item }}

                                    </template>
                                </v-list>
                            <!-- end of transaction -->
                        </v-card-title>
                    </v-card>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-card>
    </template>                 
</v-data-table>
```

And here is my method for that, here's the problem the `return response.data` does not return the value to itself `getTransactionDetails` when I call. Anyone help me with this. But if its just a normal return like `return [{value:'test'}]` it passes the value to function

```
getTransactionDetails:function($trans_id){
    const data = {
        oc_data : ['giveaways'],
        transaction_id: $trans_id.substr(1)
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('getObservedCat',data)
        .then(response=>{

            return response.data
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Here is my dispatchiing action from vuex

```
getObservedCat:({commit},obj)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            axios({
                url:'/prod/api/observredCategories',
                method:'post',
                config:'JSON',
                data: obj
            })
            .then(response=>{
                if(response.status == 200){
                    resolve(response.data)
                }
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                if(error.response){
                    reject(error.response.data);    
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: why don't you return axios itself? it contains the promise object instead of using `return new Promise () => {}` you can do `return axios({})`

Comment: @samayo Thans for that tricks, But I solved it using mapState - actions mutate state tree then I'm just calling the state from computed